# How to specify the version for a nested dependency before running npm install

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

I have the following dependency hierarchy in my project.

A@0.1.0
--- B@0.0.1
------- C@git url

I want to change the version of C. I need to do this before running npm install because trying to install from the git url specified throws an error. I know about npm shrinkwrap but that apparently requires us to run npm install first. Which throws an error at the point where tries to install C and stops. No directory is created for B after running npm install. Is there a way to specify the version of a nested dependency before running npm install. Or some other workaround to this problem?

Comment: why can't you specify this in package.json?

Comment: @DaveBriand. I'm trying to install a module A. Which has a dependency B. The changes I have to make is in the package.json of B. Is it possible do that? npm install fails without creating a directory for B.